# TaskOrchestrationContext.CallActivityAsync throws JsonException when passing DateOnly as input argument

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions-isolated

I am writing an Isolated Durable Azure Function and my Function having the `OrchestrationTrigger` throws a `JsonException` when I invoke a function with an `[ActivityTrigger]` passing a `DateOnly` as input. If I wrap the `DateOnly` value in a class it works just fine.

**Error:**
`Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'WriteDateOnly': Cannot convert input parameter 'today' to type 'System.DateOnly' from type 'System.String'. Error:System.Text.Json.JsonException: '-' is an invalid end of a number. Expected a delimiter. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 4.`

Should I wrap my DateOnly argument, is that the expected approach when working with Durable Azure Functions?

Example code to reproduce this issue:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;

namespace Sandbox.Functions
{
    public class DateOnlyOrchestrator
    {
        [Function("DateOnlyOrchestratorApi")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunApi(
            [HttpTrigger] HttpRequestData request,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient durableTaskClient)
        {
            var today = new DateOnly(2023, 4, 11);

            var orchestrationInstanceId = await durableTaskClient
                .ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync("DateOnlyOrchestrator", today)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return durableTaskClient.CreateCheckStatusResponse(request, orchestrationInstanceId);
        }

        [Function("DateOnlyOrchestrator")]
        public async Task Run(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext taskOrchestrationContext,
            DateOnly today)
        {
            var wrappedDateOnly = new WrappedDateOnly
            {
                Today = today,
            };

            // This activity is invoked successfully.
            await taskOrchestrationContext
                .CallActivityAsync("WriteWrappedDateOnly", wrappedDateOnly)
                .ConfigureAwait(true);

            // The JsonException is thrown when this activity is invoked.
            await taskOrchestrationContext
                .CallActivityAsync("WriteDateOnly", today)
                .ConfigureAwait(true);

        }

        [Function("WriteWrappedDateOnly")]
        public Task WriteWrappedDateOnly(
            [ActivityTrigger] WrappedDateOnly today)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Today is: {today.Today}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        [Function("WriteDateOnly")]
        public Task WriteDateOnly(
            [ActivityTrigger] DateOnly today)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Today is: {today}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class WrappedDateOnly
    {
        public DateOnly Today { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the `program.cs` of my Functions project I have the absolute minimum:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints?tabs=csharp#orchestrator-code-constraints) [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints?tabs=csharp)

Comment: Please help me understand why these references are relevant? The orchestrator itself receives a DateOnly as argument, which seems to me a perfectly valid use case, i.e. run activities for a given reference date. 

The reference docs only state the orchestrator itself should not determine timestamps by itself, but take if from the context. This applies not to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Durable Functions, I am able to parse Date in Visual studio in local.

I have referred to [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/how-to-use-dateonly-timeonly) for parse Date and I have referred [Git](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview.md) for Durable Function.

```cs
          {
            var date_string = "11/5/2019";
            
            var date = await context.CallActivityAsync<DateTime>(nameof(ParseDateString), date_string);
            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(PrintDate), date);
            Console.WriteLine("date "+date);
            
        }

        [Function(nameof(ParseDateString))]
        public static DateTime ParseDateString([ActivityTrigger] string dateString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dateString "+ dateString);
            return DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        }

        [Function(nameof(PrintDate))]
        public static void PrintDate([ActivityTrigger] DateTime date, ILogger log)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{date:d MMMM, yyyy}");
            
        }

        [Function(nameof(HttpStart))]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");  
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
            nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
                  return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    } }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You use a DateTime while I use DateOnly (introduced in .NET 6). I try to get things working with a DateOnly.

Comment: you can use below code for fetching the date
```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Of course I know how to transform a DateTime to a DateOnly, but that's not the point here. Apparently the `CallActivityAsync` is unable the scenario where the input argument is a DateOnly, while it works if you wrap this same value in a class.

Comment: As per the MSDoc, the CallActivityAsync method can accept any serializable object as an input param. And, there is a known issue where the method is unable to serialize DateOnly objects. Hence as a workaround, you can wrap the DateOnly value in a class and pass it as an argument to the [method](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview.md).

Comment: do you perhaps have an issue number for this known issue? I couldn't find it on github. For now I will stick to wrapping it then.